# Send scheduled mailing fails due to deprecated function CRM_Utils_Token::getTokenDetails

Tags: tokens, scheduled-reminders, cron-job, flexmailer

My send scheduled reminder cron job has been failing consistently.

The log file shows about a dozen of these errors every time send scheduled reminders fails:

```
[warning] Deprecated function CRM_Utils_Token::getTokenDetails, use If you hit this in mailing code you should use flexmailer - otherwise use the token processor.
CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedFunctionWarning
CRM_Utils_Token::getTokenDetails
::gdpr_civicrm_tokenValues
CRM_Utils_Hook::runHooks
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)
```

I use flexmailer already. The mail fails when using simple tokens like {contact.first_name}, but also when deleting all tokens from the mail body.

What could cause this behavior?

getTokenDetails is not mentioned as deprecated in their [official documentation](https://doc.symbiotic.coop/dev/civicrm/v5.20/phpdoc/CRM_Utils_Token.html) other than some other functions of CRM_Utils_Token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a png-logo pasted as part of our HTML signature:
data:image/png;base64
The image pointed to an URL as well.

Deleting it solved the problem for me - if anyone can guess why, please edit or comment.

Now there is only one instead of a dozen of these alike error messages remaining for each run of scheduled reminders, which finally finish successfully.